# Netbeans do not provide sync facility in javafx project

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, synchronization

I just started with `javafx` about 2 days ago I experienced many weaknesses between `javafx` and `Netbeans`. One of them is netbeans do not sync project files. It do not simply work as swing application as when we save or run file in swing the changing effect sync all over the project and application do not show any error and show appropriate result.
**But** in `javafx` when we change anything we have to **clean and build** the project to make it work. Is this happening to others too or there is something I have to do in my project?

In my case a single change in any file do not take effect unless I **clean and build** my project. If something wrong guide me what to do.

**Edit:** Moreover how you import something in `fxml` file I'm unable to import anything with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

Thanks

Comment: In the properties available from the context menu of the project and check, if `Compile on save` is checked under `Build > Compiling`.

Comment: @fabian it's not checked and Netbeans do not allow me to check it as it is disable.

Comment: Netbeans seems to screw up copying the resources to the build directory for this kind of project. The quick&dirty fix would be creating a new project using the `Java Application` wizard which AFAIK should create a appropriate build script copying the files & copying the files to the new project...

Comment: @fabian Yeah this way is working a bit but not the solutions thanks anyway.